# Relative/Local Accuracy (of a map): Definition & Error Calculation

Tags: accuracy

[Here](https://support.dronedeploy.com/docs/accuracy) there is a good definition for Relative/Local accuracy of map:

> This is the accuracy of a point on the map relative to other points
>   within the map/model.

It sound like theoretically we can map entire countries in local, and then just by shifting and rotating **the entire map at once**, this map will be aligned with some Global/Absolute DATUM.

So usually in specifications of map products I see:

> Global/Absolute accuracy - 1m, Relative/Local - 50cm

But isn't it extremely misleading information? In short I say so because it's impossible to map large coverage's with same local consistency.

Why this is not the correct interpretation of the terms?

The 50cm relative accuracy is within some local range, for example 1km. Thus **ain't** single shifting and rotating of entire map at once, rather than 1KM peice each time.

So if you use 10KM of this map, your accuracy is not 50cm, rather than going as square root in the number of local intervals (1KM) in your area of interest (10KM) (Basically this is just a well known math that the standard deviation going as square root, in this example it's basically means the accuracy is way worst than only 50cm).

Comment: The site you linked to related local accuracy to ground sampling distance and said local accuracy was generally 1 - 3x the GSD. Local accuracy could also be related to any distortion occurring due to the map projection. E.g. distances are distorted. You then seem to be using "local" for a "local coordinate system" which can be transformed into a global coordinate system. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually no. I'm more talking about simple situations when someone mapping using poor GPS (proxy to Global) but good measurement instruments (proxy to Local).

Comment: Then you have better resolution than accuracy. If first point was GPS but then you levelled or used a total station for the rest...then you could have better relative than absolute.

Comment: @mkennedy In case I'm doing geodesic survey, but theoretically I just can only tape measure... So the question is more about actual local accuracy meaning and error calculation.